# When I add OR in SQL statement, I get rows, but it should not

Tags: sql

I am not sure why is this happening.

When I write my first query, it returns 0 rows - which is good.

```
SELECT id, dayType, employeeID 
FROM records 
WHERE companyID = 2 
  AND employeeID = 22 
  AND endTime IS NULL
```

Then I found out that there are endtime with 0 AND NULL in column values so I added or endTime = 0, then it returns records

```
SELECT id, dayType, employeeID 
FROM records 
WHERE companyID = 2 
  AND employeeID = 22 
  AND endTime IS NULL OR endTime = 0
```

Can someone assist me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis for the correct logic:

```
SELECT id, dayType, employeeID 
FROM records 
WHERE companyID = 2 
  AND employeeID = 22 
  AND (endTime IS NULL or endTime = 0);
```